# Integer / in fortran

Tags: variables, integer, fortran

Hi I have come across something in a code like,

```
  Integer x/0/
  Real y/0.05/
```

My question is what does the /number/ represent? Does that mean that that is the value of that integer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation, you have given, is indeed a possible form of initialization. `x` will be initialized with `0` and `y` will be initialized with `0.05`.

Please note, that this notation is not conforming to the standard (thanks IanH).

Better possibilities mentioned in Fortran 2008 are (see 5.2.3 and 5.4.7):

```
integer x = 0
real y = 0.05
```

and

```
integer x
real y
data x /0/
data y /0.05/
```

Comment: be aware many compilers took such initialization to imply `save`.

Comment: This syntax was never standard Fortran (hence it wasn't "removed with Fortran 95").

Comment: @IanH Thanks. `gfortran` didn't complain while using `-std=legacy`, so I concluded it was standard at some point in the past.